# XAMPP Apache Service detected with wrong path

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I read a lot of problems about this, but I couldn't find the solution. Like a month ago, I installed a program that is called WAMP just to try it out. When I uninstalled it and tried to install Apache , it said that the path is wrong. I tried everything, and sorry if the answer of my question is too simple, but I can't fix the problem alone. Here is what XAMPP outputs in the console:

```
Apache Service detected with wrong path
Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
Found Path: "D:\programs\xampp 2016\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

Comment: Cleaned up formatting, tags, title.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on Start Menu -> Run and enter “Regedit” (sans quotes). Then you need to navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services[Name of Service]. To change the location of the exe just change the ImagePath key.

Answer (score 0):

try the below steps....

open cmd > run as administrator type the following commands

```
httpd -k shutdown
httpd -k stop
httpd -k uninstall
```

or
open powershell> run as administrator type the following commands

```
.\httpd -k shutdown
.\httpd -k stop
.\httpd -k uninstall
```

or

```
win + R
type services.msc
then find Apache24 or httpd
now open cmd > run as administrator
type sc delete "<your services name from the list for apache>"
```

thanks to the sources and contributors :)